# Use IN operator in HANA calculation view, used in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, hana

I have created the calculation view in HANA Web IDE and using the same view to query the data in SSRS report. I've used the below query to get the data set.

Select * from Hana_calculation_view
where CreatedBy IN (?)

If I use CreatedBy = ?, it just works fine but IN operator is not working if there are multiple values are there for the parameter.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Regards,
Viresh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to make this work correctly with HANA - this usually work with other DBS.

You can use an Expression to build your query.

```
="Select * from Hana_calculation_view where CreatedBy IN ('" & JOIN(Parameters!DATE.Value, "', '") & "')"
```

[image]

This is a workaround that will parse the parameters and put them in quotes in parenthesis for the IN statement and pass the query to the database.

Not sure of the HANA date syntax - I'm assuming that they use single quotes but you can substitute other characters if necessary.

Comment: Hi, I am already using the exp JOIN(Parameters!DATE.Value, "', '") in the parameter expression in the main data set. If i choose singel value from dropdown, it gives the data and for multiple values not showing any data. Thank You.

Comment: @viresh - I don't think you should use the JOIN in the Parameter Expression - SSRS should handle it correctly. This was a workaround for dbs that don't like the SSRS query syntax. Another workaround is to filter in the Dataset Filter instead of the query. The IN should work correctly there (though you do need to return more data initially from the query)..